# Function not returning properly when grabbing items (filesystem)

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have a frustrating issue happening right now. I'm trying to make a function that gets the files in a directory, but it just wont return the items.

```
function get_items(){
    fs.readdir(entire_path, function(err, items){
        console.log(items.join("\n"))
        return items.join("\n");
    });
}

console.log(get_items());
```

As you can see in this code, it console.logs the items, then returns the items, and then at the bottom it console.logs the output of the function. The console.log in the function works, but the second one does not. Why is this happening? This only happens in a function as well.

**EDIT 1**
Please don't mark as duplicate, I don't want to do

```
get_items(function(){
//do stuff
});
```

I want to be able to just do `get_items();`

**EDIT 2**
I used readdirSync instead.

Comment: readdir is async

Comment: This is a very popular question. See the duplicate for more info. You may have to dig into the answers a bit to find what applies best for you. But the concept is the same. You cannot return from within a callback.

Comment: Please read my edit, I know that it has asynchronous nature but thats not how I want this function executed.

Comment: If you don't want to use a callback, you can use `readdirSync`. But best advice is to learn how to handle async in JS.

Comment: I have tried readdirSync but it didn't return anything @elclanrs (as in it wouldnt even console.log the items)

Comment: Can you add the code for how you are using `readdirSync`?